# Build a new array from two other arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

`alphabet` is composed of letters (e.g. the English alphabet). `dictionary` is a list of objects with words and definitions, `'word'` being the key for the word value.

I want to build a new array called `frequency` which would contain the number of words that start with each letter in the alphabet array, with indices corresponding to the alphabet array.

I've managed to come up with the following:

```
alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
        frequency = dictionary.filter(item => item['word'].toLowerCase().startsWith(letter)).length;
    });
```

This gets me individual values for `frequency`. What is the best syntax in Javascript for building an array of those values? Is it another filter? Or should the code use the current `forEach` manually with a incremental index?

Comment: Can you make your question clear.

Comment: Convert frequency variable to a key-value pair such as [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), map or set

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `alphabet` variable and how you want the output result to be

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+array+frequency+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please add the values of `alphabet`, `dictionary` also the expected value for `frequency` to make it more clear.

Comment: You use the word `list`. If the dict is an array of words, then the filtered result is an array of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's get some example data. We'll ignore anything that isn't related to the question.

```js
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
var dictionary = [{'word': 'alpha'}, {'word': 'beta'}, {'word': 'balloon'}]
```

Then we'll create a `results` variable, which will hold an array of all results in alphabetical order.

```js
var results = []
```

Now we loop over the same way you did before, but we'll `push` each result to our list.

```js
alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
  frequency = dictionary.filter(item => item['word'].toLowerCase().startsWith(letter)).length;
  results.push(frequency);
});
```

As an alternative solution that allows us to more easily look through our results, we'll make results an object, and use letters as keys.

```js
var results = {};
alphabet.forEach(function(letter) {
  frequency = dictionary.filter(item => item['word'].toLowerCase().startsWith(letter)).length;
  results[letter] = frequency;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce, you can easily make a new object with the letter as the key and an array of matches as the value.

```js
const words = ["abba", "ant", "apple", "bannana", "barn", "car", "cat"];

const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");

const result = alphabet.reduce((a, letter) => {
  a[letter] = words.filter(word => word.toLowerCase().startsWith(letter));
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```